# Pendrive bootable not showing after trying to reinstall Mavericks

Tags: mac, macos, macbook-pro, usb, startup

I did the steps to reinstall OS X Mavericks. I created a bootable Pendrive but it doesn't show when I hold down "Option" at boot. I already erased my HD, so I'm stuck now!

How can I reinstall OS X Mavericks from nothing, if the bootable drive is not working?

Comment: Did you create your 10.9 installer as per: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5856 ?

Answer (score 2):

How do you know you made your drive bootable?

The first thing to attempt is to see if you erased the entire drive or just the original boot partition. Boot your Mac and hold down 'Command-R' and if it is still there you will boot into the Recovery partition. If you have a recent Mac and an internet connection then it will boot into internet recovery if you **have** deleted the Recovery partition.

Once you are in Recovery mode you can re-install the OS your Mac came with and try the Mavericks install again.